# Manually Define Fixed Widths in Data File

Tags: excel, text-editor, fixed-width

I have a fixed width data file from a third party that contains 1,000 records. It came with a separate document that displays all available columns, char start char end and char length for each column. It has thousands of columns.

My data file doesn't have data in every row so defining the fixed widths in Excel isn't feasible as I might erroneously skip a column because I can't see that it has data.

Is there a text editor that lets you manually type/define or import widths?

Comment: Do all the rows except the blank ones have the same data char start, char end and char length? If so, you could remove blank lines as a preliminary data cleaning step.

Comment: This is true but with hundreds of columns needing parsed I'm looking for a more automated approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does this "separate document" look like? Let's say I have a text file with a column of width values to be read that looks something like this:

20

25

30

10

5

23

25

10

23

I can then read the values from this text file into excel, and adjust the column widths of my spreadsheet using the following vba code:

```
Sub colWidth()
    Dim widthArray() As String
    Dim myFile, textline As String
    Dim x, y As Integer


    'example text file containing column widths
    myFile = "C:\qqq\qqq\qqq\widths.txt"

    'loop through the file and store each column width in an array
    Open myFile For Input As #1
    x = 1
    Do Until EOF(1)
        Line Input #1, textline
        ReDim Preserve widthArray(1 To x)
        widthArray(x) = textline
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    Close #1

    'using the array of column widths to adjust columns
    For y = 1 To UBound(widthArray)
        Columns(y).ColumnWidth = Int(widthArray(y))
    Next y
End Sub
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was thinking. The separate text file looks like what you've shown in your example, having a column of numbers that indicates at which character to end/start a new column.

Two questions: 1) Can I replace the myFile reference with the path/filename and expect the code to work? 2) Where do I put the code within Excel?

Comment: You would have to edit a few things for this to work. Firstly, this is currently assuming there is only one column of data in the text file (a fairly easy fix to make this work for a multi-column file if this cannot be done manually). Secondly, the **ColumnWidth** attribute should _theoretically_ be equivalent to the number of characters in the cell (see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.columnwidth), but if you have altered fonts/font sizes this may have to be scaled up/down.

Comment: To run the code, press alt + f11 (on Windows) while in the Excel spreadsheet to load the VBA console. Then, insert a new module, paste in the code, and press f5 or the green arrow to run it (see https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2013/12/06/add-run-vba-macro-excel/)

Comment: The data file has hundreds of columns needing parsed, right now it exists as a text file. The reference file with the columWidth is just a single column of numbers. Both files do not contain any text formatting.

Comment: Assuming there are no headers or anything in the reference file or changes in fonts then yes all you should have to do is edit the file path